# How with javascript for loops write variable in the php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this code:

```
<?php require_once("conection.php") ?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = function() {
            for(var = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            document.write('<?php echo i ?>');
            }
         }
      </script>

   </body>
</html>
<?php
   if(isset($connection)) {
      mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

When uploading this file I see this: **iiiiiiiiii**. How to write the code that will show me: **123456789**.
I do this because the javascript we can retrieve the text of the element, and the text should be inserted into the database.

Comment: @NgmAKumar you're kidding, right?

Comment: There are already correct answers posted, but just to add to it... As a hint, take a look at the page source when you view this in your browser.  Look at what the code becomes.  This should indicate to you that the PHP code runs *in its entirety* before the page is even loaded in the browser.  Only *after* that does the JavaScript code run.  The two can't dynamically interact the way you're trying to make them interact here.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     document.write(i);
   }
}
```

No need to use the php connection there for it.

Comment: Pay attention to the syntax error before somebody vote you down.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because PHP and JavaScript can't interact that way. Instead, you can do this:

```
<?php require_once("conection.php") ?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = function() {
            var result = document.getElementById("result");

            for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                result.innerHTML+= i + ", ";
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
       <div id="result"><div>
   </body>
</html>
<?php
   if(isset($connection)) {
      mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

1. Keep your `<script>` under `<head>` tag
2. Use some element to print your result, `document.write` clears all the content;
3. You have a syntax error on `for(var = 0`. Fixed it above.

Now, if you want to print an PHP result, you have to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php require_once("conection.php") ?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = function() {
            for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            document.write(i);
            }
         }
      </script>

   </body>
</html>
<?php
   if(isset($connection)) {
      mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```